# iOS 7 home screen wallpaper as my app background

Tags: ios, ios7, background, wallpaper, homescreen

Some iOS apps use our home screen wallpaper as the app's background, but with a blur effect on it. Can we do the same in our app? Is there an API to access to the device's home screen background?

Comment: I tried doing this with a transparent background view with a visual effect view inside it, but no luck.